# Office Access Update statement by using python PYODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

cursor.execute('Update assignments SET Files = ?, Status = ?, Progress = ?, Comments = ? WHERE assignments_primarykey = ?;', (files, status, progress, comments, task))

This doesn't work for me for some reason. It says:

cursor.execute('Update assignments SET Files = ?, Status = ?, Progress = ?, Comments = ? WHERE assignments_primarykey = ?;', (files, status, progress, comments, task))
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 6. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: One of the column names in your UPDATE statement is unrecognized. You can verify the actual column names in the table via `col_names = [col.column_name for col in cursor.columns("assignments")]`

Comment: @GordThompson it doesn't seem to be the trouble.
['Task', 'Assigned employee', 'Deadline', 'Files', 'Status', 'Progress', 'Comments']

Comment: Your table does not have a column named `assignments_primarykey`

Comment: but isn't primarykey the key column??? I've seen lots of people use it internet.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I changed the primarykey to Task. However I was convinced that primarykey stands for the key column. Isn't that a thing?

Comment: No, it isn't. A specific database *may* provide some sort of alias for the primary key column(s), but it is by no means a common thing.

Comment: Please describe your issue and use code snippets (```) to indicate code and error tracebacks. Formatting here also helps with readability and understanding :)